# Sort data in a file php

Tags: php, csv, sorting

I would like to sort some data I extracted into an .txt file.
Let's say my file describes multiples products and it looks like that :

```
[
  {
    "id" : 1,
    "Name" : "Steak",
    "Stock" : 42,
    "Date" : 29/10/2020
  }
  {
    "id" : 2,
    "Name" : "Cheese",
    "Stock" 89,
    "Date" : 29/10/2020
  }
]
```

How can I make a csv file that would have 3 rows (id, Name and Stock) and then put each information in the right row ? I want it to look like that :
[image]

I would like to do it in php. I want to precise that I'm showing an example because the real informations are confidential so I can't show it.

Comment: Search for `how to open txt file in php`, `how to convert json to array in php` and `how to create csv file in php`

Comment: None of what you say you want to do, is actual “sorting”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the JSON data into an array, then iterate the array, taking the keys and saving them as headers, you should be able to then output all of that into a csv string, which can then be wrote to a file:

```
<?php
$string = // Read JSON into variable;

$data = json_decode($string, true);

$headers = [];
$output = [];

foreach ($data as $line => $item) {
    $output[$line] = [];
    foreach ($item as $key => $row) {
        if (!isset($headers[$key])) {
            $headers[$key] = $key;
        }
        $output[$line][$key] = $row;
    }
}

$outputString = '';
foreach ($headers as $header) {
    $outputString .= $header . ',';
}

rtrim($outputString, ',');
$outputString .= "\r\n";
foreach ($output as $row) {
    foreach ($headers as $header) {
        $outputString .= $row[$header] . ',';
    }
    rtrim($outputString, ',');
    $outputString .= "\r\n";
}

// Output $outputString to file;
```

Could definitely be refactored a bit, but that should give you the basic logic of what you're trying to do